# what is 70's styles photo effect called

Tags: photoshop

What is a photo called that has 2 pictures, one of a group (usually) and the second one of a single person that is usually "floating" in a top corner of the picture?

Answer (score 4):

In the photo business, we call that a " memory mate". Typically, it's a picture of a sports team or maybe a school class group with a smaller picture of the individual in a corner.

Comment: Ah... those things.

Comment: Variations can also be used for individual sports... http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/102833-karate-kyle ;)